# Unable to install react native application on my iOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I have built a React Native app on Mac OS. I can build the app on device, but when I eject the cable, the app is disappeared. I want this app to stay in my phone permanently but it doesn't.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a production build of your app to make it "stay".

1. Visit this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device
2. Select iOS & Mac OS
3. Scroll down to **3. Build app for release** and follow the instructions there.

You can then use the release file to install the app permanently on your device.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the previous version of the app still running in the background when trying to install. I quit the app in the background and the installation succeeded.